# Preventing .hover event from being spammed if the mouse is quickly moved on and off the element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I have implemented a simple pop-up which appears if the mouse is moved over a certain element, however, I can cause a chain of `.hover` events by running my mouse over and off the element rapidly. What I mean by this is that even once I'm no longer moving the mouse the pop-up will appear and disappear multiple times. This is contrast to the CSS `:hover` specification, which triggers only once regardless of how many times the mouse is moved on and off an element.

How can I replicate this functionality? I have included an example of what I mean below, try moving your mouse in and out of the box rapidly to see the effect.

```js
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
  $('#hover').hover( function(event) {
    $('.popup').fadeIn( 200 );
  }, function(event) {
    $('.popup').fadeOut( 200, function() {
      $(this).hide();
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.popup {
  width: 200px;
  height: 75px;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  display: none;
}

.hover-box {
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="popup">
  Hello, I am a popup!  
</div>

<div id="hover" class="hover-box">
  Hover over me!
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can delay show effect a little using setTimeout function, and clear timeout on `mouseout` event. Something like this:

```js
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
  $('#hover').hover( function(event) {
    clearTimeout($(this).data('timeout'));
    $(this).data('timeout', setTimeout(function() {
      $('.popup').fadeIn( 200 );
    }, 300));
  }, function(event) {
    clearTimeout($(this).data('timeout'));
    $('.popup').fadeOut( 200, function() {
      $(this).hide();
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.popup {
  width: 200px;
  height: 75px;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  display: none;
}

.hover-box {
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="popup">
  Hello, I am a popup!  
</div>

<div id="hover" class="hover-box">
  Hover over me!
</div>
```